# Calling getCommunitySharedFiles returns error 'missing parameter communityCollectionID'

Tags: ibm-sbt

Calling getCommunitySharedFiles returns this Missing parameter communityCollectionID error in Greenhouse playground also..  According to the documentation, it should be the same as getCommunityfiles.

Comment: could you add a screenshot or indicate if you set the communityUuid ? also are you using Java or JavaScript?  what's the URL of the snippet?

Comment: The URL to the snippet is here: https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/sbtplayground.nsf/JavaSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_Files_Get_Community_Files  It's using the Java API.  FYI,  I adding this request on behalf of Philippe Riand.

Comment: it's a bug in the code, I'll have the developer look at it.

Answer (score 0):

it's an issue which is found 
https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/0f7237b6ff22fed631bde9e4e16ed9744506694c/sdk/com.ibm.sbt.core/src/main/java/com/ibm/sbt/services/client/connections/files/FileService.java#L1971

```
String requestUrl = FileUrls.GET_COMMUNITY_COLLECTION.format(this,FileUrlParts.accessType.get(accessType), FileUrlParts.communityId.get(communityId));
```

Based on the Collection enum

```
GET_COMMUNITY_COLLECTION(new VersionedUrl(v4_0, "{files}/{authType}/{accessType}/communitycollection/{communityCollectionId}/feed")),
```

The community Collection ID is never being passed, and should be part of the format command

```
public String format(BaseService service, NamedUrlPart... args) {
return builder.format(service, args);
}
```

I asked the Developer to Fix

Comment: Thanks @Paul Please keep us informed.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. It's now fixed in a recent release